# How to switch position of D3 SVG elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some SVG elements on my page that I created with D3. All are children of one parent SVG. Each contains some other D3 elements like paths and text. On the click of a button, I want two of these child SVGs to switch positions, so they move up or down on the page (all are placed above/below each other).

I already tried creating groups ("g") instead of the child SVGs and accessing/changing their positions. However, I can't seem to access the y position of the element.
I also tried using "insertAfter" but this only works with divs, not with  SVGs (however, I'm looking for a similar behaviour).

```
$(".move_up").click(function() {
  var svg = $("#second_child"); //ID is actually retrieved from an attribute of the button
  svg.insertBefore(svg.prev()); //does obviously not work
});
```

HTML for move up button (one per child SVG exists):

```
<a class="move_up">
  <span class="grey glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" title="Move up"></span>
</a>
```

HTML for SVG:

```
<div>
  <svg id="parent">
    <svg id="first_child"
      <path></path>
      <rect></rect>
      <text></text>
      ...
    </svg>
    <svg id="second_child"
      <path></path>
      <rect></rect>
      <text></text>
      ...
    </svg>
    <rect></rect>
    <text></text>
    ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

I want the first and second child SVGs to switch positions, when the move up (or respectively a move down) button is used.

Comment: Can you share the html too?

Comment: I added some HTML and some more info about what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
let group = $("#first_group");
let next_group = $('#second_group");

let diff = 58; // Height of a group
let translate_y = 0;
let translate_y_next = 0;

if (next_group.offset()) {
    if (group.attr("transform")) {
        let string = group.attr("transform");
        translate_y = parseInt(string.substring(string.indexOf("(")+1, string.indexOf(")")).split(",")[1]);
    }

    if (prev_group.attr("transform")) {
        let string_next = prev_group.attr("transform");
        translate_y_next = parseInt(string_next.substring(string_next.indexOf("(")+1, string_next.indexOf(")")).split(",")[1]);
    }

    group.attr("transform", `translate(0, ${translate_y + diff})`);
    next_group.attr("transform", `translate(0, ${translate_y_next - diff})`);
}
```

Works similar for a "Move up" button. Just make sure to change the sign in the last two lines!

May not be super elegant, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an SVG as wrapper and the positions are different to html. In SVG You need to define the X and Y position.

```js
let ids = ['ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4', 'ex5']
let btn = document.getElementById('move')

const sortArrayAsYouWish = (array) => {
    array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

const changeOrder = () => {
  let posY = 35
  sortArrayAsYouWish(ids) // change order
  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    let $el =  document.getElementById(id)  
    $el.style.transform = `translate(0, ${posY*i}px)`
  })
}

btn.onclick = changeOrder

changeOrder()
```

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 340px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
g {
  transition: transform 0.4s;  
}

text {
  fill: #fff;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

#ex2 rect {
  fill: blue;
}
#ex3 rect {
  fill: yellow;
}
#ex4 rect {
  fill: red;
}
#ex5 rect {
  fill: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div><button id="move">Move</button></div>
<svg>
  <g id="ex1">
    <rect width="120" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
    <text x="60" y="15">Hello example 1</text>
  </g>
  
  <g id="ex2">
    <rect width="120" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
    <text x="60" y="15">Hello example 2</text>
  </g>

  <g id="ex3">
    <rect width="120" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
    <text x="60" y="15">Hello example 3</text>
  </g>

  <g id="ex4">
    <rect width="120" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
    <text x="60" y="15">Hello example 4</text>
  </g>

  <g id="ex5">
    <rect width="120" height="30" x="0" y="0" />
    <text x="60" y="15">Hello example 5</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing it a bit, so multiple elements could be moved in a row (if you have more than two child groups). I determine the y value from the transform attribute (if available) and add/substract my designed position change from that. Works like a charm now!

Comment: In my opinion, I would try to sort the array of elements as you need and then I would run the sort function (`changeOrder` in this case)

Comment: I added more elements to example for explain better the idea. Regards!